# docker-py only finds podman containers being run as root user

Tags: docker, podman, almalinux

When using the docker_py library interfacing with a podman daemon, the containers object doesn't seem able to discover containers run by my user, however, are able to discover containers created by the root user.

On my box I have the following:
podman version 4.4.1
py3.9, docker == 6.1.3

for my user I run

```
podman run --it --rm docker run hello-world
```

Additionally for my user, at the same time I also run this python snippet.

```
import docker

self._docker_client: docker.client.DockerClient = docker.from_env()
containers = self._docker_client.containers.list(all=True)
print(f"containers are: {len(containers)}")
```

The most important thing I notice is that the containers object is empty, even though if I run as my user

```
podman ps --all
```

I get results returned.

If I however run the `podman run` command as the `root` user, then the python code will return that container.

I'm curious here, is it bad practice to run the docker python library against the podman daemon? I would have thought in the above case that this would have "just worked", however maybe there is something I'm missing here with the namespaces that podman uses?

Comment: How are you pointing the docker client at your podman user socket? You're creating a client via `docker.from_env()`, so are you setting `DOCKER_HOST` or configuring a docker client context? I wouldn't expect your code to work for either root or rootless podman.

Comment: @larsks  `docker.from_env()` falls back to using `unix:/var/run/docker.sock` which symlinks to `/run/podman/podman.sock` owned by root. Haven't completely confirmed this yet but expect that podman cli run is using the ```/run/user/<id>/podman.sock```. If I use `podman --url unix:/var/run/docker run ..` then I now see the containers running in python code. However using `docker.client.DockerClient(
            base_url="unix:/run/user/30770/podman/podman.sock"
        )` I get some issues with "Unable to locate server named", continuing investigating. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That url is incorrect; you would want `unix:///run/user/30770/podman/podman.sock` (and `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` or `unix:///run/podman/podman.sock` for the system socket).